# 30s of inactivity timeout will close Windows 10 logon screen

Tags: login, windows-10

In Windows 10 logon screen (not remote), an inactive time of 30s will close it. Is there any way to modify the time?

We are developing some MFA (multi-factor authentication) support, after entering the user password it will have other challenge like email/phone calls. But in some cases it may take more than 30s, Windows 10 will close the logon screen and stop any email/phone waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a customer with paid MS support account.

The registry controlling the login screen timeout is:

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI
DWORD Value: IdleTimeOut
Unit: msec
```